# [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: custom validator check failed for prop "colspan" in bootstrapvue

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I am using `BootstrapVue` in my `Vuejs` project, I face a weired issue **"Invalid prop"** with `b-table-simple` componentin`b-thead` table helper I bind colspan with array length which always gives a number, and it works fine but it generates console warning message:

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: custom validator check failed for prop "colspan".

found in

---> <BTh>
       <BTr>
         <BThead>
           <BTableSimple>
             <NationalTrends> at resources/js/components/trends/NationalTrends.vue
               <Trends> at resources/js/components/trends/Trends.vue
                 <Root>
```

When I put number (4 or any other number) it works fine without generating the warning in the console.

Below is my code:

```
<template>
<div>
<b-table-simple hover small caption-top responsive striped>
                    <caption>Commodity Trends</caption>
                    <b-thead head-variant="light">
                        <b-tr>
                            <b-th>Commodity</b-th>
                            <b-th>Current Month</b-th>
                            <b-th :colspan="selected_periods.length">Previous Period</b-th>
                            <b-th :colspan="selected_periods.length">% Change From the Previous Period</b-th>
                            <b-th :colspan="selected_periods.length" class="text-center">Direction of Change</b-th>
                        </b-tr>
</div>
</template>
```

Please help, I spent one hour trying to figure out whats the problem but no luck......

Answer (score 2):

Try to use like this:

:colspan="selected_periods.length > 0 ? selected_periods.length : 1"

Answer (score 0):

Please check selected_periods.length against that custom validator (see [bootstrap-vue source](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/blob/dev/src/components/table/td.js))

```
const digitsRx = /^\d+$/

// Parse a rowspan or colspan into a digit (or null if < 1 or NaN)
const parseSpan = val => {
  val = parseInt(val, 10)
  return digitsRx.test(String(val)) && val > 0 ? val : null
}

/* istanbul ignore next */
const spanValidator = val => isUndefinedOrNull(val) || parseSpan(val) > 0
```

```
export const isUndefined = val => val === undefined

export const isNull = val => val === null

export const isUndefinedOrNull = val => isUndefined(val) || isNull(val)
```

Comment: I suspect that selected_periods.length sometimes possibly returns undefined or something unexpected.

Comment: as I said `selected_periods.length` always returns digit

Comment: What's the initial value of selected_periods? [] ?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to remove the warning by adding a default value if null (which will not happen in my code) as below:

```
<b-th :colspan="selected_periods.length || 4">Previous Period</b-th>
<b-th :colspan="selected_periods.length || 4">% Change From the Previous Period</b-th>
<b-th :colspan="selected_periods.length || 4" class="text-center">Direction of Change</b-th>
```

Comment: again: you should initialize selected_periods with empty array and not with null value, This way selected_periods.length always works as expected in your template.